# Validation Rule for QuoteLineItem Quantity field

Tags: validation

Quantity field is a Number(10, 2) datatype User need to enter only be whole numbers like 1.00,2.00,3.00 not 1.5 or 2.75

If user enters 1.5 or 2.75 I need throw validation error message.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this generally with any number field by using a rule like:

```
FLOOR(Field) <> Field
```

You could also use any other type of formula whose purpose is to round numbers to the nearest whole number.